# flask_restful return json data in bytes

Tags: python, json, flask, flask-restful

I have the following flask app setup.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import sys
import logging

from flask import Flask, jsonify
from flask_env import MetaFlaskEnv
from flask_restful import Resource, Api
from flask_restful import reqparse
from tornado.httpserver import HTTPServer
from tornado.ioloop import IOLoop
from tornado.wsgi import WSGIContainer

class Configuration(metaclass=MetaFlaskEnv):
    """
    export PORT=80
    """
    DEBUG = True
    PORT = 5000

root = logging.getLogger()
handler = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)
root.addHandler(handler)

LOGGER = logging.getLogger(__name__)
LOGGER.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object(Configuration)
api = Api(app)

peopleDict = {}

class People(Resource):
    def get(self):
        """curl http://localhost:5000/people/
        """
        return jsonify(peopleDict)

    def post(self):
        """curl http://localhost:5000/people -d "age=22&name=john" -X POST -v
        """
        parser = reqparse.RequestParser()
        parser.add_argument('name')
        parser.add_argument('age')

        args = parser.parse_args()
        peopleDict[args['name']] = {'age': args['age']}
        return jsonify({args['name']: peopleDict[args['name']]})


class Person(Resource):
    def get(self, name):
        """curl http://localhost:5000/person/john
        """
        return jsonify({name: peopleDict[name]})

    def put(self, name):
        """curl http://localhost:5000/person/john -d "age=30" -X PUT -v
        """
        parser = reqparse.RequestParser()
        parser.add_argument('age')

        args = parser.parse_args()
        peopleDict[name] = {'age': args['age']}
        return jsonify({name: peopleDict[name]})

    def delete(self, name):
        """curl http://localhost:5000/person/john -X DELETE -v
        """
        person = peopleDict[name]
        del peopleDict[name]
        return jsonify({name: person, 'deleted':'true'})


api.add_resource(People, '/people')
api.add_resource(Person, '/person/<string:name>')


@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return 'Hello, World!'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    LOGGER.debug("server starting on port :" + str(app.config["PORT"]))
    HTTP_SERVER = HTTPServer(WSGIContainer(app))
    HTTP_SERVER.listen(port=app.config["PORT"])
    IOLoop.instance().start()
```

I also have the test case written like this:

```
import json
import unittest
from ddt import ddt, data, unpack
from app import app

@ddt
class ApiTestCase(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.client = app.test_client()

    def testPostPeople(self):
        result = self.client.post('/people', data={'name':'john', 'age':22})
        print (result.data)
        values = json.loads(result.data)
```

and I'm getting the follwoing error when I run the test cases

```
b'{\n  "john": {\n    "age": "22"\n  }\n}\n'
E
======================================================================
ERROR: testPostPeople (tests.test_api.ApiTestCase)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/transfer/tests/test_api.py", line 15, in testPostPeople
    values = json.loads(result.data)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/json/__init__.py", line 312, in loads
    s.__class__.__name__))
TypeError: the JSON object must be str, not 'bytes'

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.015s
```

I do NOT understand why I'm getting the json string in bytes, it should be in str. I can call decode() on result.data, but I really want to fix this probme in the app, not in the test cases.

Comment: why do you think it "should" be in str? do you have any reference? if you look at Tornado docs, you must see that the response body is in bytes.

Comment: Ok, I see, Tornado is returning in byte string, if there a way to convert it back to str? Or byte string is the HTTP standard?

Comment: yes, please see my answer

Comment: The data transport between server and client is in byte stream. So the test client return `bytes` to you. The best practice is decode bytes to on input, process, encode text on output. The `requests` also provide `text` to provide `unicode(str)` and `content` to provide `str(bytes)`.